# What's the resson the skin looks bluish when having cyanosis?

Tags: pathophysiology

What's the reason the skin looks blue when having cyanosis? What's the relationship between lack of oxygen of the bluish appearance?

Comment: Have you thought about the coloring of arterial and venous blood?

Comment: Yes, and it still doesn't explain to me the bluish colour. (lack of red doesn't mean blue)

Comment: What color is venous blood?

Comment: Darker red than the arterial one.

Comment: @UbiquitousStudent No, it's not simply darker red. It has a purplish hue, and to make purple you mix which two colors?

Comment: 1. I held many tubes with venous blood, and I didn't notice purplish hue. (See also here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood#/media/File:Venous_and_arterial_blood.jpg) 2. Red and blue give purple. Where this *blue* comes from?

Comment: [Advertising my answer about pulse oxymetry which touches on the different absorption of oxy-Hb (oxygenated, arterial blood) and desoxy-Hb (desoxygenated, venous blood)](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/14044/8212)

Comment: Please, explain the relationship between the cyanosis colour to your answer. Thank you

Comment: @UbiquitousStudent Doesn't really make sense to consider the color of venous blood after it's been exposed to oxygen...

Comment: Any blood of living human exposed to oxygen... otherwise he'll not be alive.

Comment: @UbiquitousStudent You realize that venous blood has had the O2 it once carried stripped away, right? And although colors are a subjective thing difficult to describe precisely, venous blood does indeed have a purple hue to it as noted by _many_ observers throughout history.

Answer (score 1):

The skin of a caucasian-skinned person with cyanosis *is* described as bluish, but [it is still more reddish than blue](https://osuwomeninphysics.wordpress.com/2015/03/11/everyday-physics-why-do-veins-look-blue/). The bluish jumps out at us in comparison with healthy well-oxygenated blood.

The colors we see are the product of the incoming light, and the proportion of the wavelengths that are absorbed, scattered, or reflected. Because skin and arteries/capillaries/veins are translucent, there's normally quite a bit of red light scattering and reflection going on. However when looking at veins or cyanotic skin, there's less reflection of the red wavelengths, and the skin looks darker and bluer than we're used to.

If you look at a photograph of [someone with Raynaud's or cyanotic hands,](https://www.firstaidforfree.com/what-is-cyanosis/) you'll see that there's still quite a bit of red!

Comment: This may partly explain why we see different colors, but it doesn't answer the question of why cyanosis causes those changes to occur.